# Summing of groups

Tags: mysql, group-by, sum

I need to get the sum of group values. I tried this query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM amx_bans WHERE ban_length=0 and expired=0 AND server_name LIKE '%COD%' GROUP BY server_name
```

But it returns something like this:

> COD MOD 32
>
> COD MODX 32
>
> COD MODY 32

This variations of names is in fact the same server so I need the sum of this values, in this case 96, how can I accomplish that?

Answer (score 0):

If this query returns all the data for 1 server then just remove the `GROUPING` and you will get that 96 sum in one row. All the variations of `COD` will be grouped in one count.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM amx_bans WHERE ban_length=0 and expired=0 AND server_name LIKE '%COD%'
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you should be using `sum(..)` instead of count(*).

```
SELECT
    server_name, SUM(<your column name>) 
FROM
    amx_bans
WHERE
    ban_length=0 AND
    expired=0 AND
    server_name LIKE '%COD%'
GROUP BY
    server_name
```